# Роутинг и htaccess yii 2

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, yii2

Доброго времени суток.

Только начал осваивать Yii2 и столкнулся с проблемой правильного построения .htaccess и настроек urlManager.

проект расположен на локалке по адресу:

```
http://localhost/base
```

файл index.php расположен по адресу

```
http://localhost/base/web/index.php
```

хочется получить url  вида site/index где `<controller>/<action>`

для этого прописую в файле .htaccess в директории web:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

А в config добавляю в components :

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ]
        ]
```

В результате файлы по адресу :

```
http://localhost/base/web/index.php
```

Становятся недоступны т.к. выбивает ошибку. Как и по адресу `http://localhost/base/site/index`
Пожалуйста подскажите в чем заключается ошибка и как будет правильно?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: какую ошибку выбивает?

Comment: Internal Server Error (500) The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: Значит ругается сам yii, посмотрите в логах - может там будет объяснение, чего ему не хватает.

Comment: файл в runtime\logs чистый

Comment: Для дальнейшего понимания проблемы необходимо более развернутая информация по ошибке 500.

Comment: Где еще может хранится информация об ошибках ?

Comment: В логах http сервера

Comment: `[Sun Feb 21 03:19:40.203050 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 1152:tid 1088] [client ::1:55754] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://localhost/base/assets/`

Comment: у вас есть папка assets в web/ каталоге?

Comment: да по этому адресу есть такая папка, в корневом каталоге тоже есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось настроить с такими параметрами

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
            ),
        ],
```

htaccess в корне куда переместил index.php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /listnews/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

В папку  {root}/web/ кладем такой .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

в корень сайта кладем такой .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

Правила в конфигурации прописываем так:

```
'request' => [
    'baseUrl' => '',
],
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        ''=> 'site/index',
        '<action>'=>'site/<action>',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Сделал. `The requested URL /site/index was not found on this server.` по адресу `http://localhost/site/index` и 500 `http://localhost/base/web/index.php`

Comment: Изменил ответ, проверьте

Comment: тоже самое, и в логи ничего не бьёт

Comment: mod_rewrite есть и включен?

Comment: @Shadow33, хочу обратить внимание, что все 3 блока изменились в ответе. Включая настройку в конфиге приложения.

Comment: действительно mod_rewrite был отключен по адресу `site/index` все та же ошибка а по http://localhost/base/web/index.php   теперь подключается шаблон но контент возвращает 404 и в логах имеется `Next exception 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Page not found.' in C:\wamp\www\base\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php:96
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\base\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#1 C:\wamp\www\base\web\index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#2 {main}`